# Using Unicode strings in DllImport with a DLL written in Rust

Tags: c#, rust, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to call a DLL written in Rust from a C# program. The DLL has two simple functions that take stings (in different manner) and prints to the console.

### Rust DLL code

```rust
#![crate_type = "lib"]
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_char};
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn printc(s: *const c_char){
    let c_str : &CStr = unsafe {
        assert!(!s.is_null());

        CStr::from_ptr(s)
    };

    println!("{:?}", c_str.to_bytes().len()); //prints "1" if unicode

    let r_str = std::str::from_utf8(c_str.to_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", r_str);
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn print2(string: String) {
    println!("{:?}", string)
}
```

### C# console program code

```cs
[DllImport("lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void print2(ref string str);

[DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void printc(string str);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    var graw = "yeyeye";
    printc(graw);
    print2(ref graw);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("calamity!, {0}", ex.Message);
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For the `print2` function it keep printing garbage on screen until it causes `AccessViolationException`

The 2nd `printc` function does print the string, but only if `CharSet.Unicode` is not set. If it is set, it will only print the first char, hence the `println!("{:?}", c_str.to_bytes().len());` will print `1`.

I believe that `Cstr::from_ptr` function does not support Unicode, that is why it returns only the first char of the string.

Any idea how to pass Unicode string as parameters to Rust DLLs?  Is it possible to make things simpler like in `print2` function?

Comment: I am not familiar with C#, but does it use C-style strings? I would be surprised. I would imagine that this is the issue, you're trying to pass a C# string as a C string.

Comment: (and print2 can't work, because C doesn't know what Rust strings are and how to make them)

Comment: @Steve C# marshals strings as C strings

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use UTF-8. That's `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str + "\0")` and marshaled as `[In] byte[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check [the documentation on `CharSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset.aspx), you'll see that `CharSet.Unicode` tells .NET to marshal strings as UTF-16 (*i.e.* two bytes per code point).  Thus, .NET is trying to pass `printc` what should be a `*const u16`, *not* a `*const libc::c_char`.  When `CStr` goes to compute the length of the string, what it *sees* is the following:

```
b"y\0e\0y\0e\0y\0e\0"
```

That is, it sees *one* code unit, then a null byte, so it stops; hence why it says the length is "1".

Rust has no standard support for UTF-16 strings, but *if* you're working on Windows, there are some conversion methods: search the docs for `OsStrExt` and `OsStringExt`.  Note that you *must* use the docs that installed with the compiler; the ones online won't include it.

Sadly, there's nothing for dealing directly with null-terminated UTF-16 strings.  You'll need to write some unsafe code to turn a `*const u16` into a `&[u16]` that you can pass to `OsStringExt::from_wide`.

Now, Rust *does* use Unicode, but it uses UTF-8.  Sadly, there is no direct way to get .NET to marshal a string as UTF-8.  Using any other encoding would appear to lose information, so you either have to explicitly deal with UTF-16 on the Rust side, or explicitly deal with UTF-8 on the C# side.

It's *much* simpler to re-encode the string as UTF-8 in C#.  You can exploit the fact that .NET will marshal an array as a raw pointer to the first element (just like C) and pass a null-terminated UTF-8 string.

First, a static method for taking a .NET string and producing a UTF-8 string stored in a byte array:

```
byte[] NullTerminatedUTF8bytes(string str)
{
    return Encoding.GetBytes(str + "\0");
}
```

Then declare the signature of the Rust function like this:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void printc([In] byte[] str);
```

Finally, call it like this:

```
printc(NullTerminatedUTF8bytes(str));
```

For bonus points, you can rework `printc` to instead take a `*const u8` *and* a `u32`, passing the re-encoded string plus it's length; then you don't need the null terminator and can reconstruct the string using the `std::slice::from_raw_parts` function (but that's starting to go beyond the original question).

As for `print2`, that one is just unworkable.  .NET knows *nothing* about Rust's `String` type, and it is in *no way* compatible with .NET strings.  More than that, `String` doesn't even have a guaranteed layout, so binding to it safely is more or less not possible.

All that is a very long-winded way of saying: don't use `String`, or any other non-FFI-safe type, in cross-language functions, *ever*.  If your intention here was to pass an "owned" string into Rust... I don't know if it's even *possible* to do in concert with .NET.

*Aside*: "FFI-safe" in Rust essentially boils down to: is either a built-in fixed-size type (*i.e.* *not* `usize`/`isize`), or is a user-defined type with `#[repr(C)]` attached to it.  Sadly, the "FFI-safe"-ness of a type isn't included in the documentation.

Comment: It's easy to get .net to marshal as UTF-8. MS has never pretended UTF-8 does not exist. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is what is needed here. Marshal as `byte[]`. Manual zero termination needed. Are you aware that when MS added Unicode to support to Windows, that UTF-8 actually did not exist?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I dunno; it keeps treating CP 65001 like it doesn't really exist and no one should use it, not to mention PowerShell's pig-headed stubbornness in encoding all text it outputs as UTF-16 despite just about nothing being able to read it.  I didn't consider re-encoding the string on the C# side because I was sticking to what you can do *just* with the dllimport annotation and *also* because I don't have a C# setup to actually test anything.  As for that last point; I know UTF-8 didn't exist, but it doesn't make it any less of a frustration *now*.  Aah, hindsight. :P

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't provide any (tested) help on the C# side; I've made the answer a community wiki if you want to make some changes on that end.

Comment: OK, let's see if we can wiki this between us. I know C#, you know Rust.

Comment: The edit I made is compatible with `void __cdecl print(char* str)` where `str` is null terminated and encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just occurred to me: this still has the issue of truncating any string that contains interior nulls.  Presumably, the signature could be changed to `[In] byte[], uint` / `*const u8, u32` to fix that.  That would *also* simplify the code on the Rust side a little.  Is there any easy way to abstract that?  I'm assuming the best you could do is do the UTF-8 transcode, store it, then pass that plus `str.Length`.

Comment: That's a little harder to abstract because there are two arguments. But yes, you'd do it the way you describe. Generally this is a non issue. It's often no problem to ban interior nulls.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Aye, I've decided against further additions; it was starting to drift from the original question.  Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer, and sorry for troubles, I will try it once I am home. I am just wondering what's the difference between `[in]` and `in` in c#.

Comment: Well, the latter is not part of C#. Perhaps you think of `out`. As for `[In]`, that could be omitted. But I'm using it here almost as documentation. It tells the marshaller to marshal the data to the caller, but not back from the caller. But in reality arrays of blittable types are pinned for marshalling so they are always `[In,Out]`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for your support again, I never thought that in C# you can apply attributes to function parameters, I mistook the `[In]` with `out` modifier. a lot I learned from you guys today and still a lot I should learn about data marshalling. Again one day lived new things learned.

Comment: Just an addition, `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)` could also do the work without trailing `\0`

Comment: @MusuNaji No. It might just happen to work by accident but you've got a buffer overrun there. Put the null terminator back.

Comment: I'm disappointed that the answer says this: "Sadly, there is no direct way to get .NET to marshal a string as UTF-8. Using any other encoding would appear to lose information, so you're struck dealing with UTF-16 in Rust, I'm afraid." I really wish the Rust experts could tidy up that part of the answer. I did my bit!!

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot better!