# How should I marshall a Rust function with a &str, Option, and String and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rust, marshalling, dllimport

The following code is in Rust:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
pub extern fn generate_work(input_hash: &str, max_iters: Option<u64>) -> Option<String> {
    let bytes = Vec::from_hex(input_hash).unwrap();
    generate_work_internal(&bytes[..], max_iters)
}
```

I have the following code in C#:

```cs
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
private static extern string generate_work(string input_hash, ulong[] max_iters);
```

I'm getting the error:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I have tried other signatures, but none has worked.

Comment: I don't know rust at all. Your C# declaration implies that the return value is a null terminated character array allocated on the COM heap. The marshaler deallocation it with a call to CoTaskMemFree. I don't think that your rust function meets that contract. How do you think the returned string is to be deallocated?

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like `*const c_char` instead of rust `String`? Also, I think you need `CallingConvention.Cdecl`, because by default it's Stdcall.

Comment: Net library was designed to prevent blue screen errors.  So extra protection is added to Net which is called managed.  Calling unmanaged c language required copying unmanaged objects to managed objects using the Marshal Class.  Your error indicates the managed object is point to an invalid address.  A string in c# is a two byte class while in c language it is a one byte[] terminated with a '\0'.  If you do not terminate the byte[] or do not copy object to managed space you will get the error you are seeing.

Comment: @jdweng most of what you say there is wrong. Unmanaged user space code cannot produce blue screens. The distinction that us relevant us kernel mode code vs user mode, not unmanaged vs managed. Copying is not always required. Blittable types can be marshaler by pinning them. C# char is 2 bytes, but so is wchar_t in C which is the native character type of the OS.

Comment: You can't use those fancy rust types in interop. Go with plain pointers and repr(c) structs.

Answer (score 4):

As described in my [FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/), you cannot pass complicated Rust-specific types via FFI functions. You **must** use only types that are known to the C ABI. In your example, these types are not known:

- `&str`
- `Option`
- `String`

Instead, you will be required to only use basic C pointers. A NULL pointer can represent `None` for a string, but for an `Option<u64>`, you will need to break it up into two values, a boolean and the real value. Your FFI function will look something like:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
use std::ptr;

#[no_mangle]
#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
pub extern "C" fn generate_work(
    input_hash: *const libc::c_char,
    max_iters_present: bool,
    max_iters: u64,
) -> *const libc::c_char {
    let input_hash = if input_hash.is_null() {
        return ptr::null();
    } else {
        unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(input_hash) }
    };
    let input_hash = match input_hash.to_str() {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(_) => return ptr::null(),
    };
    let max_iters = if max_iters_present {
        Some(max_iters)
    } else {
        None
    };

    let result = inner_code(input_hash, max_iters);

    match result {
        Some(s) => {
            match CString::new(s) {
                Ok(s) => s.into_raw(),
                Err(_) => ptr::null(),
            }
        },
        None => ptr::null(),
    }
}
```

Note that this returns an allocated string that you need to pass back to Rust to deallocate. Again, as described in [the FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/), you'll need something like

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn free_a_string(s: *mut c_char) {
    unsafe {
        if s.is_null() { return }
        CString::from_raw(s)
    };
}
```

[Converting a string to Rust is easy](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_arguments/):

```cs
[DllImport("string_arguments", EntryPoint="how_many_characters")]
public static extern uint HowManyCharacters(string s);
```

[Returning a string requires a lot more trickery, sadly](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/):

```cs
internal class Native
{
    [DllImport("string_return")]
    internal static extern ThemeSongHandle theme_song_generate(byte length);
    [DllImport("string_return")]
    internal static extern void theme_song_free(IntPtr song);
}

internal class ThemeSongHandle : SafeHandle
{
    public ThemeSongHandle() : base(IntPtr.Zero, true) {}

    public override bool IsInvalid
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public string AsString()
    {
        int len = 0;
        while (Marshal.ReadByte(handle, len) != 0) { ++len; }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        Marshal.Copy(handle, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        Native.theme_song_free(handle);
        return true;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html)
- [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html)
- [Taking string arguments via FFI](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_arguments/)
- [Returning strings via FFI](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/)
- [Using Unicode strings in DllImport with a DLL written in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32812769/155423)

Comment: How is the returned string going to be deallocated? And what does the C# p/invoke declaration look like?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [You've already answered the P/Invoke part of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32816043/155423), which is why I linked to it.